# What is a keyboard shortcut in Keynote to edit a text object without clicking it?

Tags: keyboard, keynote, text

Suppose I have a text object currently selected on a slide. I'd like a keyboard shortcut that lets me edit the text without erasing it, just like `F2` does in the Microsoft world. `Return` is close: it enters text editing mode, but erases the contents of the text object.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: A quick workaround is to press `Return` and then `⌘ cmd`+`Z`.

Comment: Oh that is just horrifying. But yeah, I'll do that until I figure out something better.

Answer (score 1):

If you press control-q and then control-e it lets me edit the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that pressing `control + q` twice goes into edit mode but I have not seen this documented anywhere.

Also, pressing `control + o` adds a newline below the current line without moving the cursor ‍♂